# What is the Ruby equivalent of Python's iter()/next()?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-5, ruby-2.6

In python I can get an iterator from any iterable with `iter()`; and then I can call `next(my_iter)` to get the next element.

Is there any equivalent in ruby/rails?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`.to_enum` will yield the enumerator. For an example `a.to_enum` will yield the enumerator and you can iterate it from there like `a.to_enum.each{|x| p x}.`

Or without loop, you can take the element like

```
p a.to_enum.next
```

Comment: But again, that requires a looping construct (i.e. `each`). How can you get an item from an enum without that.

Comment: You said you can call `I can call next(my_iter)` same can be done here `a.to_enum.next` or you can save `b=a.enum` and then `b.next`

Comment: I see! Thanks, but you should mention it in the answer; because `next` is the actual answer.

Comment: @mshsayem I have added.

Answer (score 1):

Without a loop:

```rb
words = %w(one two three four five)

my_iter = words.each

puts my_iter.next  # one
puts my_iter.next  # two
```

But what is the point of an iterator that isn't in a loop? It's kind of the whole *raison d'etre* of them...

Answer (score 0):

There are many iterators in Ruby as follows:

1. Each Iterator
2. Collect Iterator
3. Times Iterator
4. Upto Iterator
5. Downto Iterator
6. Step Iterator
7. Each_Line Iterator
8. Explaining Types of Iterators

Each Iterator: This iterator returns all the elements of an array or a hash. Each iterator returns each value one by one.
Syntax:

```
collection.each do |variable_name|
   # code to be iterate
   continue if condition # equivalent next in python 
end
```

In the above syntax, the collection can be the range, array or hash.

referenced from https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/ruby-types-of-iterators/

Comment: Well, I was not asking for looping. Each of the examples there actually requires a loop/block/proc to get any element.